# Good food-grade electric pump for transferring wort?

Tags: equipment, pump

I need a pump to use for transferring wort from a 55 gallon drum. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: Off-topic, vote to close.

Comment: @theraccoonbrew would you feel differently if it was wort instead of sap? either can be used as a substrate for ethanol production.

Comment: I suppose, though I'm apparently unable to rescind a vote to close.  I assumed you were making syrup and the quantities you describe certainly sounded beyond typical "home" brewing.

Comment: @theraccoonbrew indeed, some will be used for wort, some for syrup, and the large scale is a consequence of available resources. I have taken off the flow rate requirement though. Still, I expect that it will take as much as 200 gal of sap to make 20 gal of wort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know several brewers who use a pump made by [March](http://www.marchpump.com/pumps/).   You can find them at many of the larger homebrew shops.

Answer (score 6):

The March 809HS is the standard.

Answer (score 0):

For wort you can use any centrifugal pump.

Following are some important points while selecting a pump:
1. Internal for pump should be of stainless steel.
2. Inlet and outlet should be of stainless steel.
3. Use SMS union type end fitting.
4. Use EPDM/ PTFE gasket material.
5. As wort is hot liquid, it can create cavitation. So while searchingfor a pump, ask supplier to supply with low suction pressure capacity.